# #fetch and #save on a Backbone model instance is not working

Tags: backbone.js

My model has a url property defined.

However, when I try to call fetch or save on it, I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'ajax' of undefined
```

Any solutions are appreciated.

My backend is only a simple RESTful interface.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Can you try adding it?

Comment: Could you please post the code of your model and the piece where you try to call fetch/save.

Answer (score 2):

You have forgoten to add jquery or zepto.js to your side. Backbone tries to call `$.ajax(params);` and `$` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by including jquery or zepto, but you must remember to include one of these *before* backbone. The other solution that doesn't force your files to be ordered is to call `setDomLibrary` at document ready:

```
Backbone.setDomLibrary(jQuery);
```

This will bind Backbone to the dom library of your choice.